# Issue with Accordion JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am a novice in jquery and am trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong with JQuery. It will not perform the accordion effect, I cant get the **`$row[cat_Name]`** to display and the **`$sub[cat_Name]`** but not as an accordion **(almost like a list but not)**. I'm not sure if I have included jQuery UI library or if it is below the jquery library properly. The error that I am receiving is: TypeError: $(...).accordion is not a function

The outcome is a list of main category elements **`$row[cat_Name]`** with subCategroy **`$sub[cat_Name]`** elements underneath the **`$row[cat_Name]`** but not hidden. What am I doing wrong?
**My Code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Shop Homepage - Start Bootstrap Template</title>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<link 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
<!--jQuery code-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- <link 
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href = "font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script> 

<script src= "typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>
$( function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
  collapsible: true
});
} );
</script>


 <style>
 .sideBar{
 float: left; 
 }
 ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 }
 #accordion {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 width: 170px;
 }
 #accordion div {
 display: block;
 background-color: #ff2727;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 5 5 5 7px;
 list-style: circle;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 }
 #accordion ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 }
 #accordion ul{
 display: none;
 }
 #accordion ul li {
 font-weight: normal;
 cursor: auto;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 0 0 0 7px;
}
 #accordion a {
 text-decoration: none;
 }
 #accordion a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 }
 </style>         


 <div class = "navbar-default sidebar" role= "navigation">
 <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
 <div id = "accordion">
 <?php
 $database = new DB();
 $query = "select * from category where cat_SubCat IS NULL";
 $rows = $database->get_results($query);
 foreach ($rows as $row)
 {
 echo "<h3><a href='#' class='list-group-item'>" . $row[cat_Name] . "</a>
 </h3>";
    $query2 = "select * from category where cat_SubCat= $row[cat_ID]";
    $subs = $database->get_results($query2);
    foreach ($subs as $sub)
    {
    echo    "<p><a href='#' class='list-group-item'>" . $sub[cat_Name] . "
 </a></p>";
    }

 }
 ?>
 </div>
 </div> 

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure of this what you were trying to achieve but there is simple way of using accordion. here is simple example

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div id = "accordion">
 <?php
 $database = new DB();
 $query = "select * from category where cat_SubCat IS NULL";
 $rows = $database->get_results($query);
 foreach ($rows as $row)
 {
 echo "<h3><a href='#' class='list-group-item'>" . $row[cat_Name] . "</a>
 </h3>";
    $query2 = "select * from category where cat_SubCat= $row[cat_ID]";
    $subs = $database->get_results($query2);
    foreach ($subs as $sub)
    {
    echo    "<p><a href='#' class='list-group-item'>" . $sub[cat_Name] . "
 </a></p>";
    }

 }
 ?>
 </div>
```

Here i am using jquery-ui plugin where it has accordion facilities and much more. Now you can run a foreach loop on the div and achieve the results what you wanted. Hope this helps you.

Comment: still not working i changed the code to model what you illustrated in your answer but the $sub[cat_Name] doesn't tuck under $row[cat_Name] nor do i see how it knows<h3> vs. <p> tags

Comment: @AdamZeigler run the snippet code and have a look at it. When you click on the .$row[cat_Name]. you can see the .$row[sub_cat]. gets hidden. They  get toggled. Since php codes cannot be understood you will be seeing lots of code in the snippet. Please ignore it. If this is not what you wanted please explain me little bit more.

Comment: so do I have all the libraries for this to be accomplished because it just gives me something like a list of all the categories instead of just the categories and sub_cats hidden

Comment: See my js file i would have included jquery-ui script, you must initialize it .